Snap bone 'a' to bone 'b' , similar to "keep offset"
How can I use python to make bone a snap to bone b in pose mode, like a parent-child relationship with offsets maintained. I tried using "matrix" but the results were terrible.
Even if I don't move bone 'a' at all, bone 'b' will still change strangely
ps: I am trying to write a script to snap ik to fk
'''
def execute(self, context):
    obj = context.object
    if obj.type != 'ARMATURE' or context.mode != 'POSE':
        self.report({'WARNING'}, "Must be in Pose mode with an Armature object selected")
        return {'CANCELLED'}

    bone_a = obj.pose.bones.get('a')
    bone_b = obj.pose.bones.get('b')

    if not bone_a or not bone_b:
        self.report({'WARNING'}, "Bones 'a' and 'b' must exist")
        return {'CANCELLED'}

    # Calculate the offset matrix
    offset_matrix = bone_b.matrix.copy() @ bone_a.matrix.inverted()

    # Apply the offset to bone_b, using bone_a's matrix
    bone_b.matrix = bone_a.matrix @ offset_matrix

    return {'FINISHED'}

'''
